# How to comput Hessian or second derivative using chain rule.

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus, chain-rule, hessian-matrix

Suppose I have function $L=f(\mathbf{W}\mathbf{x})$, where $\mathbf{W}$ is a matrix, $\mathbf{x}$ is a vector, and the $f(\cdot)$ produces a scalar. I am wondering how to compute the Hessian of $L$ against $\mathbf{x}$.

The most hard part is that I am confusing to align the dimension, I do not know where to put $\mathbf{W}$ and whether the transpose is needed.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3575991/357854) is one way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to compute the gradient and Hessian of the function $L(x) = f(g(x))$, where $g(x) = Wx$. The derivative of $g$ is $g'(x) = W$. By the chain rule,
$$
L'(x) = f'(g(x)) g'(x) = f'(Wx) W.
$$
Note that $L'(x)$ is a row vector. If we use the convention that the gradient is a column vector, then the gradient $\nabla L(x)$ is the transpose of this row vector:
$$
\nabla L(x) = L'(x)^T = W^T f'(Wx)^T = W^T \nabla f(Wx).
$$

The Hessian $HL(x)$ is by definition the derivative of the function $h(x) = \nabla L(x)$. So, using the chain rule again, we obtain
$$
HL(x) = W^T Hf(Wx) W.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have a question that does the $\nabla_f(Wx)$ and $Hf(WX)$ you write mean take derivative against $Wx$?

Comment: @ZhengyiLi Here $\nabla f(Wx)$ is the gradient of $f$ evaluated at $Wx$, and $Hf(Wx)$ is the Hessian of $f$ evaluated at $Wx$.